# "IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type java.util.HashMap is not of type of the persistent entity" When using embedded document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am upgrading from spring-boot 1.5.10 to 2.1.1. However, I get following error "IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type java.util.HashMap is not of type of the persistent entity".

Here are my classes:

```
@Document
public class AbstractMongoDocument extends AbstractPersistable<String> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1621100881694109722L;

  @CreatedDate
  private DateTime creationDate;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private DateTime modificationDate; 
}


public abstract class AbstractAuditableMongoDocument extends AbstractMongoDocument {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4962248712372390885L;

  @Version
  private Long version;

  @LastModifiedBy
  private String updatedBy;


  @CreatedBy
  private String createdBy;

}


public class Email extends AbstractAuditableMongoDocument {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7601333678154632864L;

  private String hashedEmail;

  public Email() {
  }

  public Email(
        String hashedEmail) {
    this.hashedEmail = hashedEmail;
}


@Validated
@Document
public class Account extends AbstractMongoDocument {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -8228412296744241027L;

  @Indexed(unique = true)
  protected String primaryEmail;

  Map<String, Email> emails = new HashMap<>();
}
```

This set up worked fine on 1.5.10 with mongodb but no longer does and is throwing the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException mentioned above.

Comment: can you show how the entity looks like in mongo/json?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your type from long to Long.

Long is an object and it can be serialized/deserialized via the java serialization mechanism.

Same thing if you have HashMap in your model it should be just Map.